# DeviceIoControl with input unsigned char buffer C++

Tags: c++, buffer, deviceiocontrol

I have a problem with using `DeviceIOControl` to put 128 byte buffer to my driver, i use this code:

```
int Initialize(unsigned char* public_signature, int size)
{
    int ret = DeviceIoControl( 
    DeviceFileHandle,
    2236440,
    public_signature,
    size,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL);



    if(ret != 0)
        return 0;

    wprintf(L"Format message failed with 0x%x\n", GetLastError()); // always error 0x6!

    return 1;

}
```

I always get 0x6 error, what i'm doing wrong?

**upd**
My handle creating function:

```
int CreateFileHandle()
{
    DeviceFileHandle = CreateFile( L"\Device\test",
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    0);
    if(DeviceFileHandle)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the 1st parameter of `CreateFile`. In your example, it would try to open a file, not a device. In addition, you didn't escape backslashes in the string. `\t` and similar are interpreted as special characters in C++.

The device name should be `"\\\\.\\Device\\test"`.